# Remover janela do cmd/dos ao chamar App Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui

Fiz um programa em Python que possui uma interface, mas quando o executo, a janela do interpretador Python aparece junto. Como remover essa janela do CMD que se abre juntamente com a aplicação?

Segue a foto...
[image: TELA PRETA QUE ACOMPANHA A APLICAÇÃO PYTHON]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use o `pythonw.exe` para rodar a aplicação, ao invés do `python.exe`; Para isso, renomeie o seu arquivo de `app.py` para a extensão `app.pyw` pois essa extensão já vem associada ao `pythonw.exe`.

Answer (score -2):

Insira o seguinte script logo ao iniciar seu código:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.FreeConsole()
```